# Indent children nodes in XSL-FO

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xsl-fo

I have XML structure like this

```
<TestLog>
   <TestLogItem id="0" pid="-1">
      <Message>some message</Message>
   </TestLogItem>
   <TestLogItem id="1" pid="0">
      <Message>some message</Message>
   </TestLogItem>
   <TestLogItem id="2" pid="0">
      <Message>some message</Message>
   </TestLogItem>
   <TestLogItem id="3" pid="2">
      <Message>some message</Message>
   </TestLogItem>
</TestLog>
```

Every **TestLogItem** node has "**id**" and "**pid**(parentId)". I am showing the messages in table rows and just want to indent every message if its a child of previous node i-e its PID is equal to previous node ID. I cannot figure out how to do it in xsl-fo to convert it to pdf.

> Any TestLogItem node can have any number of TestLogItem children
>   nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Process the first item, then do a recursive call to find the children of the first item:

```
<xsl:template match="Testlogitem">
    <fo:table-row...>
    </fo:table-row>
    <fo:table-row>
        <fo:table-cell padding-left="1 cm">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[@pid=./@id]"/>
        </fo:table-cell>
    <fo:table-row>
</xsl:template>
```

(you may have to use a variable instead of referring to ./@id, can't test this right now)

Edit: 
I've added the indent code. Basically, you create a table row for level 1. Inside that row, you add a row for level 2 which has an indent.

This is a dirty trick: nested tables can lead to trouble. The alternative is to use a two-step process:

1. Use an XSLT to transform your XML into a nested structure. Write the nesting level into the output XML:

> TestLogItem id="1" pid="0" level="2"

2. Then use FO to process the nested structure:

> xsl:template match="Testlogitem/@level='2'"

This works without building a nested table.

Comment: Use the `current` function, i.e. `following-sibling::*[@pid=current()/@id]`

Comment: Well I did this part through <xsl:for-each select="TestLogItem">. But I don't know how to indent children. I mean one Tab for first level children, 2 Tabs for 2nd level children and so on. Can you please modify your answer and explain a little about the indent ?